# C++ generate list of pages in category mediawiki api

Tags: python, c++, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am currently working with python's mwparserfromhell and mwclient in order to parse pages and do the usual bot related things (build lists, edit etc; all approved of course). I recently read that embedding C++ code into python (I am using pybind11, but there are other ways) could significantly speed up the python script. I ran a couple larger test and confirmed this.
I was wondering how you could retrieve all the pages in a category in C++? My goal is to retreive it in C++ in order to speed up the execution of an existing python script if possible. With python (using mwclient) it is
`site = mwclient.Site(('https', 'en.wikipedia.org'), '/w/')`
`for page in site.Categories[cat_name]:`
`.    #do something`
What would it be for C++?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#C++